# How to save scripts, images and css files into browser cache?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I have been trying to enable Caching for my web-page. I find-out so much post related to Caching static file in browser cache, but i did't get success.

I try for both server side or client side code for it:

**SERVER SIDE**

I tried to put code for set-up a "Cache-Control" header on server side page-load(write code in C#) :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(dt);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(dt.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks));
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945898/cache-control-headers-in-asp-net)

**CLIENT SIDE**

In javascript after some googling i find a "Preloading images" technique , but applying this code also not give me correct solution of storing file into cache.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962580/fast-loading-of-many-images-on-html/9962592#9962592)

**HTML META TAGS**

Added following tags in my page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="private"/>
<meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="Wed, 16 oct 2013 11:12:01 GMT"/>
```

did't get success.

[Reference](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html)

Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong here?

And any one suggest me for perfect solution/full tutorial for enabling cache to store static files into browser cache.

Thanks in advance....!!!!

Answer (score 1):

First i think you have confused caching with preloading images.
If what you really need is caching, check your browser whether caching is disabled.Because scripts,images and css are cached defaultly by browser.

Next how did you check whether those are cached?

Comment: Checking for cached element used "Browser console" like : Chrome object inspector

Answer (score 1):

You could use "cache-manifest" which uses AppCache of the browser.
It allows you to run your website offline also.
Head to http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html for more information.
Hope it helps!!